# How to check several conditions at the same time in python?

Tags: python, multiple-conditions

The actual question is : I want to check the state of charge of several batteries at the same time and perform actions(charge/discharge/amount of charge/discharge) in parallel, based on the values obtained.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... But `1 <= i <= 50`?

Comment: is `T` a function here that will take a parameter `i` and computate some function returning a result? and the function has to be computated for all values of `i` from 1 to 50?

Comment: Viewed 21 times

-1


The actual question is : I want to check the state of charge of several batteries at the same time and perform actions(charge/discharge/amount of charge/discharge) in parallel, based on the values obtained

Answer (score 0):

If `T` is an object:

```py
all([T[i] == 1 for i in range(1,51)])
```

If `T` is a function:

```py
all([T(i) == 1 for i in range(1,51)])
```

`all` Is a built-in function that checks whether every one item in the list is evaluable to `True` (may those be `True` itself, or `1`, a non-empty string or list, ...)

The expression `[f(x) for x in iterable]` is called list comprehension and is a shortcut to create a list, equivalent to:

```py
l = []
for x in iterable:
    l.append(f(x))
```